# How to stringify in Java

Tags: java, c++, string, macros

In c++ we could use macro as

```
#define check_and_log_warning(x) if (!(x)) {log_error(#x); cout<<__LINE__;}
```

I want to get values of a boolean expression and also use it as a string.
Getting the line number inside macro would be added benefit.

Can something like this macro be written in Java ?
I recently moved from c/c++ to java, so I am wondering could such thing be done in c++ without macro ?

Comment: get used to the fact you can't do many of things you used to in Java..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preprocessor is what I miss from C/C++ in Java. There are ways ..., but they are Java ways.

1/ Assertions:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html

2/ Logs:
The one that I use is https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/

(over log4J or whatever you want)

To print line numbers in log messages, you can use something like:
`int lineNo = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2].getLineNumber();`

Edit:
Be warned: unlike `__LINE__` in C++ getting the stack trace incurs a performance penalty. Be nice :)

Comment: Just found out AssertionError could be caught. But for warnings I think try catch with assert is too much.

Comment: Nope, don't do it. Assertions are designed in a certain way.

Answer (score 2):

There is no macro facility in Java.

You would be using a logging framework (of which there are plenty to choose from).

```
if (! theActualConditionNotJustX) myLogger.error("describe problem here");
```

The logging backend (if configured that way) makes sure to capture and display line numbers. There is some runtime cost for this, but it is usually negligable, especially where actual "errors" are involved (it can get a bit costly for trace-level logging).

Comment: This doesn't even remotely answer the question if and how `log_error(#x);` and `cout<<__LINE__;` are possible in Java.

Comment: They are not possible in Java. It simply does not have a macro system. Don't shoot the messenger...

Comment: Not sure about the line number, but getting a string "true" or "false" from a bool value should be no problem? The OP knows that there are no macros.

Comment: Didn't he want the expression  (whatever x is to be replaced with), rather than "true" or "false"?